# Stop words analyzer in elasticsearch in a cluster

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, master-slave

I want to know that analyzer (in elasticsearch) should only be implemented on master node or has to be implemented on all the nodes separately?

Could not find an accurate answer.

Please help!

Thanks

---

```html
{
filter: {
spanish_stemmer: {
type: "stemmer",
language: "spanish"
},
spanish_stop: {
type: "stop",
stopwords: "_spanish_"
}
},
my_analyzer: {
spanish: {
filter: [
"lowercase",
"spanish_stop",
"spanish_stemmer"
],
tokenizer: "standard"
}
},
mappings: {
customparent: {
properties: {
name: {
type: "string",
analyzer: "my_analyzer"
},
title: {
type: "string",
analyzer: "my_analyzer"
},
fullImageAltDescription: {
type: "string",
analyzer: "my_analyzer"
}
}
}
}
}
```

Adding Logs : -

I am using Elasticsearch(2.4.1v) Spring data transport client to fetch the data from elasticsearch got stuck with below error  : -

org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:206) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction$1.onFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:152) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:46) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:872) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:850) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.onFailure(TransportService.java:387) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:39) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [match] analyzer [my_analyzer] not found
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.MatchQueryParser.parse(MatchQueryParser.java:101) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.innerParse(IndexQueryParserService.java:320) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:223) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:218) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:856) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:667) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:633) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeDfsPhase(SearchService.java:264) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:360) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:357) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
00:52:06.100 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
00:52:06.100 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Sep 05, 2017 12:52:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures {[tdPbTD9IQhSuvkFMYt1WbA][catalogviews][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Shellshock][my_ip:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match":{"title":{"query":"Top Coat","type":"boolean","operator":"OR","analyzer":"my_analyzer","fuzziness":"1","minimum_should_match":"95%"}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[match] analyzer [my_analyzer] not found]; }{[tdPbTD9IQhSuvkFMYt1WbA][catalogviews][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Shellshock][my_ip:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match":{"title":{"query":"Top Coat","type":"boolean","operator":"OR","analyzer":"my_analyzer","fuzziness":"1","minimum_should_match":"95%"}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[match] analyzer [my_analyzer] not found]; }{[tdPbTD9IQhSuvkFMYt1WbA][catalogviews][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Shellshock][my_ip:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match":{"title":{"query":"Top Coat","type":"boolean","operator":"OR","analyzer":"my_analyzer","fuzziness":"1","minimum_should_match":"95%"}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[match] analyzer [my_analyzer] not found]; }{[tdPbTD9IQhSuvkFMYt1WbA][catalogviews][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Shellshock][my_ip:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match":{"title":{"query":"Top Coat","type":"boolean","operator":"OR","analyzer":"my_analyzer","fuzziness":"1","minimum_should_match":"95%"}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[match] analyzer [my_analyzer] not found]; }{[tdPbTD9IQhSuvkFMYt1WbA][catalogviews][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Shellshock][my_ip:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/dfs]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"match":{"title":{"query":"Top Coat","type":"boolean","operator":"OR","analyzer":"my_analyzer","fuzziness":"1","minimum_should_match":"95%"}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[match] analyzer [my_analyzer] not found]; }] with root cause
[catalogviews] QueryParsingException[[match] analyzer [my_analyzer] not found]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.MatchQueryParser.parse(MatchQueryParser.java:101)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.innerParse(IndexQueryParserService.java:320)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:218)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:856)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:667)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:633)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeDfsPhase(SearchService.java:264)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchDfsTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:357)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, The problem was in analyzer mapping itself as mentioned by Ansaldos. I Had to put my_analyzer in analyzer block. i have added correct mapping below.

> { "settings":{ "analysis":{ "filter":{ "spanish_stop":{ "type":"stop",
>   "stopwords":"*spanish*" }, "spanish_stemmer":{ "type":"stemmer",
>   "language":"spanish" } }, "analyzer":{ "my_analyzer":{
>   "tokenizer":"standard", "filter":[ "lowercase", "spanish_stop",
>   "spanish_stemmer" ] } }, "mappings":{ "catalogviewparent":{
>   "properties":{ "title":{ "type":"string", "analyzer":"my_analyzer" },
>   "fullImageAltDescription":{ "type":"string", "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
>   }, "name":{ "type":"string", "analyzer":"my_analyzer" } } } } } } }

Answer (score 0):

You have to set in all node.

For example, if you set synonym analyzer with your own dictionary, you have to place synonym.txt in the specific folder in all node.

Edit:
Looks like your mapping is ok, try to add 'type' custom to your analyzer.

```
"analyzer": {
    "spanish": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "spanish_stop",
            "spanish_stemmer"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, will try it and let you know.

Comment: Hi Ansaldos, I am getting an error : - exception is Failed to execute phase [dfs], all shards failed; shardFailures ------->  and ------> QueryParsingException[[match] analyzer [] not found ............ Can you please help

Comment: The exception says your analyzer missing - so maybe you forgot to add to all nodes. Check it again, if the problem still exist please show your mapping.

Comment: I have tried putting our analyzer on all the nodes but still din't work. I think there is some setting that i am missing in .yml file. But still dont know how to fix.

Comment: Please show your mapping, maybe there is the answer. For the last chance you can try it on one node, not in cluster.

Comment: I am updating my question please have a look at my mapping. Thanks.

Comment: I did update it (Adding "type": "custom",) but it didn't work. Updating it to custom. Found out the issue in analysis block. :) ...Had to add analyzer block before mentioning my analyzer. Just now found it. Will post the exact mapping once I have completed full implementation. Thanks very much for your help.